# Vector text rendering system in Direct3d

Tags: c++, vector, fonts, directx, direct3d

Does anyone know of an implementation of vector fonts in directx?

If not does anyone have a good starting place for this?

Or even any examples of a reader written in Directx with basic zoom support.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for DirectWrite? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have to use direct3d for this task.

Comment: I am really just looking for a way to have clean high quality zoomable fonts in directx.  They can be fairly cpu intensive, as I won't be rendering anything else.  But I need to be able to fill a screen with the text.

Comment: DirectWrite is implemented on top of D3D; how is using that different than using some other library that internally sits on top of D3D? FWIW, I don't know of any system that uses D3D for rasterizing the glyphs to a bitmap; they all (including DWrite) do that on the CPU and then use D3D for pixel-level operations like AA blending and composition. Once rasterized, limited amounts of scaling can be done by D3D without re-rasterizing.

Comment: Would I just be better off writing a renderer using D3DXCreateText?

Answer (score 1):

Direct vector fonts don't work to well in D3D, as it requires an intermediary texture to hold rasterized data(verts or pixels) and need to do a lot more extra work, thus you need a approach them a little differently to get them working easily and efficiently(if you are performance constrained/care about performance). You should use signed distances fields for this (they up-scale VERY well, but are horrid for down-scaling if your fonts are complex. Hard edges also don't store too well, but this can be fixed by using two channels to store data. Distance fields also allow easy smoothing, bolding, outlining, glowing and drop shadows), al la valve's improved alpha tested  advanced vector texture rendering (which incidently references a paper on vector fonts, if you do want to go that way). It is heavily shader reliant (though it can be done in FFP via alpha testing, but using smoothstep in the pixel shader provides a far better result with minimal overhead), but one doesn't need anything beyond ps v1. see http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications.html for the paper, see the shaders in valves source sdk for a complete implementation reference. (I incidently just built a Dx11 based text renderer using this, works wonderfully, though I use a tool to brute force my sdf's so I don't need to create them at runtime).

Comment: +1 for the link to distance fonts (seriously people, _use this stuff_), but -1 in saying that D3D can't use vector fonts. A vector font just means using triangles to draw the font, rather than rasterizing them. What you have to do is generate a mesh for each glyph, rather than resterizing the glyphs. It's not a simple process, but it's certainly doable.

Comment: @nicol: seems you caught me while I was still fixing it up and fleshing it out. Updated to be a little clearer about using vector fonts in D3D.